# Interpreting an unsigned (long) int as signed in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, int, unsigned, signed

I want to reinterpret the 32 bits of an `unsigned long` as a `signed long`. The exact same bits, just considered as a 2's-complement integer instead of as an unsigned integer. I don't think simply casting it to `long` will do the trick. Am I wrong?

Or perhaps there's a better way. I'm using an unsigned long as a timer. Occasionally I read its current value and compare it with a previous reading (both `unsigned long`s) to see how much time has passed. I need to handle a possible overflow, which would cause the current value to be LESS than the previous value. Interpreting both values as signed longs and subtracting seems to give the right answer.

I tried this:

```
return reinterpret_cast<long>(time4) - reinterpret_cast<long>(currTimeLo); // treat unsigned as 2's complement
```

but just got a compiler error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.7 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328"
invalid cast from type 'long unsigned int' to type 'long int'
```

Comment: Seems to me that the same thing should work with unsigned values. Can't you check if the second one is smaller than the first one?

Comment: If, in the normal case, the new value is greater than the previous value, I can simply subtract. But when there's an overflow, the new value is less than the previous value, and simply subtracting doesn't work.

Comment: If the new value is greater than the previous value, I can simply subtract. But when there's an overflow, the new value is _less_ than the previous value, and simply subtracting doesn't work. Example using 8-bit values: say the previous value is 0xFA (250 decimal) and the new value is 0x15 (21 decimal) because the counter has overflowed. Considering these as unsigned values, we'd be subtracting 250 from 15. I'm not sure what happens if you get a negative result using unsigned values. Reinterpreting them as signed values, we'd be subtracting -6 from 21, giving the correct answer of 27.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Considering these as unsigned values, we'd be subtracting 250 from 21."

Comment: At least one internationally recognized C++ expert has done what you did here, so it's not an error that only novices engage in. I know because I mailed him and asked to ask us to not publish posting (in clc++m), which he did. :) Anyways, `reinterpret_cast` only directly reinterprets pointers and references, not integral values. In this case the reinterpretation can be effected by a `static_cast`, with one caveat: that g++ is known for exploiting every little formal loophole to trip up the practically minded programmer. So you may have to test and search for relevant options. On Arduino.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf *"with one caveat: that g++ is known for exploiting every little formal loophole to trip up the practically minded programmer. So you may have to test and search for relevant options. On Arduino."* And that is exactly what I feel is missing from the answer below. If you feel like discussing, feel free to join the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102110/discussion-between-baum-mit-augen-and-paul-evans).

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<long&>(time4)` is what you are looking for.  Reinterpretation must be with a pointer or reference type . Otherwise you are just doing a value conversion.   (Note: using reinterpret might not be the best way to solve the problem you are trying to solve)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the deeper/original problem of checking how much time has passed by comparing two unsigned counters, where there might have been 1 single wraparound:

simply subtract the earliest from the latest using unsigned arithmetic.

Assuming your `currTimeLo` is a counter value for the current time, and `time4` is some earlier value, and they're both of unsigned type (or the one of signed type promotes up the unsigned type of the other),

```
return currTimeLo - time4;
```

This is because C++ guarantees that unsigned arithmetic is performed modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>, where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation of the unsigned type.

In the case where there's been more than 1 wrap-around this approach won't work. In that case you need to use types with larger number range.

---

Regarding the question title's problem of interpreting an unsigned value as a 2's complement signed value:

First note that it's not necessary. It's the Y in an X/Y problem. Getting the difference between two counters, where the latest might have wrapped, is the original X, and it has a trivial solution (above).

---

But then, since it's what's asked about in the title:

As far as I know all extant C++ implementations are for architectures where signed integers use 2's complement representation.

The Holy Standard™ leaves it up to the implementation to define the result of casting to a signed integer type when the original value can't be represented in that type. Any reasonable C++ implementation will simply let you do that via a `static_cast`. Hence,

```
return static_cast<long>(time4) - static_cast<long>(currTimeLo);
```

**But** there is no guarantee that your compiler in Arduino is reasonable regarding this matter.

You will have to check that, and use the relevant options if necessary, assuming that the behavior can be adjusted if it's unreasonable by default.

Workarounds include

- casting pointers or references via `reinterpret_cast`,
- copying bytes via e.g. `memcpy`, formally safe but complex and needlessly potentially inefficient,
- using a formally UB union member access, or
- safe but complex, splitting the value up and recombining.

The last point can be done in a nearly elegant way that someone posted in response to the language lawyer variant of this question earlier on SO. Unfortunately I don't remember that trick, only that it impressed me for being so obvious yet one I didn't think of. But I recommend the simple `static_cast`, properly tested.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `static_cast`, something like:

```
static_cast<signed long>(your_unsigned_long)
```

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers whether or not it will do the right thing on Arduino.

Comment: @BaummitAugen This is how you you do it in C++ regardless of Arduino -- or does Arduino use a non-C++ something it calls C++?  If so, why is the questions posted as C++ and not "that Arduino thing it calls C++ that isn't really C++ at all"?

Comment: `static_cast` is only strictly defined by the standard where the source fits into the destination, the rest is implementation defined. So you would have to prove with some platform documentation that it does the right thing for the  "big corner cases".

Comment: @BaummitAugen Of course, it's a cast from unsigned to signed.  But surely it's only being done because it *can* be done.  I naturally assumed that this was the case, why else do it?  And what other "cast" is gonna magic you outta the "big corner cases" where it's just a stupid thing to do?

Comment: At least it compiles. I wonder why "reinterpret_cast" doesn't.

Comment: The question at hand is *"What will be done if `currTimeLo > LONG_MAX`?"*. This is implementation defined, so what will his implementation do?

Comment: Actually, it is not even clear that `static_cast` will preserve the bit pattern for values that fit.

Comment: Because `reinterpret_cast` isn't the thing to do in such a case, `static_cast` is.  But you *better* know what you're doing 'cause *all* cast are dangerous!  If you want purity, redesign you code so you don't *need* these shenanigans.

Comment: @user3238181 Because `reinterpret_cast` is not for integer convervisions. If you want to use the `unsigned long` as series of bytes, you may cast its address to `char*`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen You down voted my `static_cast` because converting through a pointer is, ah, *better* than an underflow?  Now you have to deal with that along with endian issues!

Comment: @PaulEvans The standard guarantees that one can view about anything as series of bytes by casting its address to `(signed/unsigned) char*`. This is what the exception in the Strict Aliasing Rule is for. I do not know whether or not that is what OP wants and needs, neither do I know whether `static_cast` does what he wants on his platform. I downvoted because you fail to address that central issue: *"Does your answer actually solve the problem on OP's platform?"*

Comment: @BaummitAugen The standard says *where* that casting to `(signed/unsigned) char*` addresses endian issues? Is this the Arduino version of C++ (that can't therefore be C++)?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Casting to `char*` always *"works"* on every platform, fwiw. That is not an answer as I have no idea whether or not that is what OP needs, that's why I did not post an answer. But what you posted isn't either, unless you state why your approach works. A priori, that is quite unclear. (Reply to edit that changed meaning of original comment).

Comment: Of course it does not address any endianness issues, it just gives you the object represented as a series of bytes. Not more, not less.

Comment: @BaummitAugen How on earth does that help with converting an `unsigned long` that's too large to fit into a `signed long`?  Why not simply test it before the `static_cast`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102110/discussion-between-baum-mit-augen-and-paul-evans).

Comment: Upvoted because this is the reasonable in-practice answer. The really-pedantic-formal version has been asked and answered earlier on SO. It's ugly.

Comment: Oh, **removed** yovote after edit because this is now no longer an answer. Should maybe be a comment.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.- Gladly rolled back, only did that because of discussion but rather side with you

Answer (score 0):

In 2's complement, a simple cast between signed and unsigned works, because it wraps the value modulo 2<sup>n</sup>, i.e. treats the same bit pattern as the other type. For example `(long)0xFFFFFFFFu` returns -1

However, the thing is that both *addition and subtraction produce 1 more carry/borrow bit*. That extra bit has to be stored some where along with the low 32 bits. So simply casting the values to `signed` and subtract doesn't work for all the cases, although it'll work for values that aren't very far from each other. Try `LONG_MAX - LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MIN - LONG_MAX` to see how the result can't be stored in a `long` even when both operands are `long`s

To get over this, the only ways are using a wider type

```
return static_cast<long long>(time4) - static_cast<long long>(currTimeLo);
```

or handle the big int arithmetic manually

```
unsigned long timeDiff;
if (time4 > rcurrTimeLo) // time hasn't overflowed and time4 is later than rcurrTimeLo
{
    timeDiff = time4 - rcurrTimeLo;
    // do something, for example set overflow/later flag:
    later = 1;
}
else
{
    timeDiff = rcurrTimeLo - time4;
    // set "earlier" flag
    later = 0;
}
```

If you use it in a function, you must return both the overflow carry and the low 32-bit difference, so the first solution seems to be easier on a 32 or 64-bit computer, and the second will be faster on a 8-bit MCU like ATmega

If you can guarantee that the 2 operands are never more than `LONG_MAX` far from each other then a simple `static_cast` to long will work

```
return static_cast<long>(time4) - static_cast<long>(currTimeLo);
```